# Зачем в Unity корутины?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Зачем в Unity корутины?
Ведь, насколько я понял, они позволяют выполнять параллельно какие то действия, во время основной работы программы. Цикл ожидания подключения там крутить. 
В Unity в каждом скрипте мы можем завести Update,FixedUpdate,LateUpdate.
При этом у нас есть такой отличный метод как InvokeRepeating, который тоже может

параллельно что то своё запускать, с нужной частотой, и не раз в каждом скрипте.

При том что самих скриптов может быть сколько угодно.

Есть ли какая то реальная необходимость сопрограмм в Unity? Может, они лучше с точки зрения производительности? Или могут применяться более точно?

Comment: в Update,FixedUpdate,LateUpdate и InvokeRepeating нельзя написать `yield return ...;`  они будут очень сильно ругаться на это. для чего нужен yield - можно почитать в справочнике по C# на msdn например

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Во-первых, сразу напишу, что не совсем корректно сравнивать корутину с Update,FixedUpdate,LateUpdate и InvokeRepeating. Ибо она может выполняться только один раз. Например

```
void Start() {
    Debug.Log("Start game");
    StartCoroutine(wait());
}

IEnumerator wait() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    Debug.Log("Coroutine is work");
}
```

выведет *Start game* и через 3 секунды *Coroutine is work*. Всё. Никаких повторных вызовов.

---

Далее.

Отличие её от всех вышеперечисленных методов как минимум в наличии ключевого слова `yield`.  Когда в методе-итераторе (коей является корутина) встречается оператор `yield return`, возвращается выражение *expression* и сохраняется текущее положение в коде.    Выполнение будет продолжено из этого местоположения при очередном вызове функции итератора.

Пример

```
void Start () {
    StartCoroutine(Test(FinalAction));
}   

IEnumerator Test(Action act) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Debug.Log("Test" + i);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
        Debug.Log("Test" + i + i);
    }        
}
```

Будет выведено "Test0", а через 1,5 секунды "Test00", "Test1" (т.к. программа продолжило выполнение с момента где остановилась и потом опять продолжила цикл)... потом "Test11", "Test2" и т.д.

Таким образом корутина позволяет прерывать вычисления, отдавать ресурсы в основной поток, а потом возобновлять следующую часть вычислений.

---

Другой пример: нам нужно инстанциировать 10.000 объектов. Порциями по 10-100 или просто в цикле, неважно. Если мы воткнем это в методе Update, то пока цикл не отработает обновления экрана не будет, приложение "висит" все это время. У пользователя "бомбит". То есть корутину можно применять для длительных операций, которые можно "размазать" по кадрам. Причем (как написано выше) можно вызывать примерно следующую последовательно действий:

```
// счетчик цикла
Debug.Log("Инстанциируем объекты и складируем их в массив");
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
Debug.Log("делаем доп работу с этим массивом");
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
Debug.Log("Еще какая-то работа");
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
```

другой пример с пулями:

```
void Start () {
     StartCoroutine("FireThriceAndWait");
 }

 IEnumerator FireThriceAndWait () {
     while (true) {
         fire();
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
         fire();
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
         fire();
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
     }
 }

 void fire(){
     Instantiate(enemy_bullet,this.transform.position, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.transform.position- this.transform.position));
 }
```

Такую работу проделать InvokeRepeating не позволит в принципе.

Еще пример. Мы хотим, чтобы до прогона действий и после что-то происходило, например логирование сообщений сделано что-то или нет. Как это делать в InvokeRepeating или Update? Вешать всякий флаги было сделано что-то или нет, зашел в метод или нет? Зачем, если можно сделать её в корутине

```
void Start () {
    StartCoroutine(Test(StartAction, FinalAction));
}

IEnumerator Test(Action actBefore,Action actAfter) {
    actBefore();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Debug.Log("Test" + i);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
        Debug.Log("Test" + i + i);
    }

    actAfter();
}


void StartAction() {
    Debug.Log("I'm a start action");
}

void FinalAction() {
    Debug.Log("I'm a final action");
}
```

Ну и еще пример.. допустим хотим мы заставить мигать спрайт (уменьшить прозрачность, увеличить) с интервалом 0.5 сек. Поставим методы в Update - будет виснуть основной поток. Для InvokeRepeating придется ставить разные флаги и доп функции - был ли вызван нужный метод или нет, если да, то повторять другой метод, если нет то первый...Сопрограммой решается это так

```
IEnumerator Test() {
    while (true) {                   
        var color = obj.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;            
        for (float i = 1; i >= 0; i-=0.1f) {
            color.a = i;
            obj.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = color;
            yield return null;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        for (float i = 0; i < 1; i += 0.1f) {
            color.a = i;
            obj.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = color;
            yield return null;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    }
}
```

Циклы можно вынести в отдельные методы - но не суть. Факт в том, что если запустить то сопрограмма будет работать параллельно без зависаний и сложных манипуляций.

---

А еще корутина может дожидаться действий от ForFixedUpdate, т.е. прерывает выполнение до кадра, в котором обновляется физика (вызывается посредством WaitForFixedUpdate) или конца фрейма (WaitForEndOfFrame). Что бывает полезно сделать и для того же InvokreRepeating придется лепить что-то для этого.

---

**В итоге**. Как я описал выше: корутину можно применять для длительных операций, которые можно "размазать" по кадрам от которых главный поток не повиснет. Для некой отдельной микропрограммки, которая будет работать параллельно (пример с миганием спрайта, или запустить персонажа бродить в одну сторону и в другую "tween"), которую сложно зарепитить из-за разности действий.

Да и не стоит забывать, что в том же Update инструкции происходят последовательно, а значит десяток методов с циклами, в которых некие действия, поставленные один за другим будут выполняться последовательно и дольше, нежели корутины и от этого может зависеть сама игра: игрок прыгнул вверх 10 раз, а потом стрельнул 10 раз или прыгнул-стрельнул 10 раз - разница.

Надеюсь я не запутал вас)

Comment: Хороший ответ, ёмкий. Единственное - смутил последний абзац. Корутина не выполняется быстрее Update и работает она тоже последовательно и более того она работает в том же потоке, что и Update.

Comment: @MikhailEfremov у меня нет в нем ничего из того, что перечислили............................там написано, что последовательные инструкции в Update, например 5 циклов `for`  подряд с 10000 итераций каждый, будут выполняться дольше, нежели если их размазать по, например 5  корутинам и запустить параллельно.

Comment: В этом и состоит смущение:) Каким образом 5 корутин будут работать быстрее, чем один Update? Корутина - просто отдельно "контролируемый Update", т.е., "размазать на 5 корутин", это то же, что и "размазать на 5 апдейтов".

Comment: Если запустить последовательно 5 for с 10000 итерациями в Update, они выполнятся последовательно, спору нет. Но, если их же запустить в корутине эффект будет таким же, за исключением остутствия контроля за очередью выполнения. Если не использовать yield, конечно. Но yield не про скорость, он про задержку.