# SignalR асинхронное подключение + Unity3D

Tags: c#, asp.net, unity3d

Пытаюсь разобраться с тем, как выполнить асинхронное подключение к хабу в `SignalR`. Изначально использовал такой код:

```
public static void ConnectSignalR()
{
    Debug.Log("Starting SignalR...");

    if (_chatHubConnection == null)
    { 
        _chatHubConnection = new HubConnection(ServerURL);
        _chatHubConnection.Error += _chatHubConnection_Error;

        Debug.Log("Connection to " + ServerURL + " complete.");

        _hubProxy = _chatHubConnection.CreateProxy("ChatHub");

        Debug.Log("Proxy created.");

        stateSub = _hubProxy.Subscribe("CatchState");
        stateSub.Data += GetMessage;
        exSub = _hubProxy.Subscribe("HandleException");
        exSub.Data += GetMessage;

        _chatHubConnection.Start();
        Debug.Log("Started!");
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что пока идет попытка подключения к хабу, Unity зависает полностью, невозможно воспроизвести анимацию ожидания или вообще какое-либо действие сделать. Я хочу попытаться запустить метод подключения асинхронно, но во-первых, никогда с этим не сталкивался, во-вторых в Unity не поддерживается асинхронность (насколько мне известно). Предположительно код будет выглядеть так (тестировал в консольном клиенте - работает), но насколько это правильно мне неизвестно:

```
public static async Task ConnectingAsync()
{
    _hubConnection = new HubConnection(connectionUrl);
    await _hubConnection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    });

    hub = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");

    hub.On<string>("HandleException", message => HandleException(message));
    hub.On<string>("CatchState", message => Console.WriteLine(message));
}
```

Собственно, помогите разобраться, что и как нужно сделать.

**UPD. Сам код на Unity:**

```
private static HubConnection _chatHubConnection = null;
public static IHubProxy _hubProxy;

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(OnStart());
}

IEnumerator OnStart()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);

    Debug.Log("Starting SignalR...");

    if (_chatHubConnection == null)
    {
        _chatHubConnection = new HubConnection(ServerURL);
        _chatHubConnection.Start();

        _chatHubConnection.Error += _chatHubConnection_Error;

        Debug.Log("Connection to " + ServerURL + " complete.");

        _hubProxy = _chatHubConnection.CreateProxy("ChatHub");

        Debug.Log("Proxy created.");

        _chatHubConnection.Start();
        Debug.Log("Started!");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Unity не поддерживается асинхронность` - серьезно? в игровом движке, где операции проходят одновременно и реагируют на нажатия кнопок одновременно прорисовывая интерфейс и движения персонажей вы утверждаете что нет асинхронности? Вот это да...

Comment: Почитайте про корутины (coroutine) - должно помочь

Comment: Если запустить подключение в корутине ничего не изменится - приложение так же зависнет и будет ждать результата подключения, после этого только вернется контроль. Когда я писал про асинхронность я имел в виду отсутствие поддержки async/await, Task. Корутины ведь это пресвдоасинхронность.

Comment: `приложение так же зависнет и будет ждать результата подключения, после этого только вернется контроль` - вы делаете что-то не так. совсем не так..... или расскажите почему все примеры https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/570573/191482 рабочие и не приводят к зависанию основного потока.......... корутины, по-сути, это и есть обертка над Task ...... т.к. на самом деле в Unity в большей степени идет работа с фреймворком, у которого свои реализации и обертки над стандартными функциями C#

Comment: Я добавил код, который в Unity выполняется.