# Неправильная работа оператора в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Оператор должен работать так: если случайное число будет равно нулю (0), то вложенный оператор увеличивает значение переменной `timeRemaining` до 40, если нет — то останавливать все на три секунды. И потом повторить снова. Вместо этого срабатывает и `if` и `else` и все вперемешку. Подскажите, как исправить?

```
void Update()
{
    int rand = Random.Range(0, 2);
    if (rand == 0)
    {
        if (timeRemaining < 40) 
        {
            timeRemaining += Time.deltaTime * 5f;
            Debug.Log ("random " + (byte)timeRemaining);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы уверены что вам нужно случайное число каждый кадр? В коде ошибок нету, думаю ошибка в логике.

Comment: @pavel честно говоря не уверен, но не могу понять как сделать по другому

Comment: @Jonathan я думаю не стоит использовать Thread в Unity. Они вроде не предназначены для этого. хотя странно, что компилятор не ругался. зачем ты вообще гасишь главный поток? что ты пытаешься сделать? Может тебе надо делать `Time.timeScale = 0` ? Какова вообще задача? Мне кажется тебе надо использовать корутины (Coroutine)

Comment: задача такая, прикрепить этот код к нескольким элементам и менять их цветовой канал в интервале 40, рэндом нужен для того чтобы они не повторялись и все было хаотично

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все проще:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    float timeRemaining;
    float timer;

void Update()
{
    float td= Time.deltaTime;
    if (timer <= 0f)//ждем таймер
    {
        if (timeRemaining < 40)
        {
            timeRemaining += td * 5f;
            Debug.Log("timeRemaining=" + (byte)timeRemaining);
        }
        else//создаем новый таймер
        {
            timeRemaining = 0f;
            timer = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1f, 3f);//UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 3); для целых
            Debug.Log("wait "+ timer + " seconds");
        }
    } else timer -= td;//уменьшаем таймер каждый кадр


 }
}
```

Ну или если прям хочется корутин:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    float timeRemaining;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TestCor());
    }

    IEnumerator TestCor()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            timeRemaining = 0f;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(UnityEngine.Random.Range(1f, 3f));
            while(timeRemaining < 40)
            {
                timeRemaining += Time.deltaTime * 5f;
                Debug.Log("timeRemaining=" + (byte)timeRemaining);
                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Да действительно, проще обойтись без корутин. Все так же работает. Благодарю.

Comment: @Jonathan Не советую 1-ый вариант из этого ответа, ибо это не сильно благоразумно делать еще какие-то условия поверх доп условий основного блока. Потом еще может добавится условие и будет еще один вложенный `if`, потом еще. 
Вместо этого обычно ииспользуют логику `if (!flag) return;`, чтобы избавиться от всех этих лестниц условий и нагромождений оберток. Не буду спорить, что у меня вариант тоже нуждается в улучшении, но конструкци вида `if { if { if { }}}` лучше избегайте.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, может вы и правы, но для моих скромных задач первый пример кода сработал очень даже хорошо, вскоре попробую ваш вариант и перепишу код, спасибо за совет

Comment: @Jonathan то, что он рабочий - я и не сомневаюсь. вот на сколько верен подход - другой вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется надо (можно, во всяком случае) сделать так:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rangee : MonoBehaviour {

    private float timeRemaining = 0f;
    private int workLimit = 10;
    private bool flagToStopWork = false;

    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(WaitALittleBit(0));
    }

    IEnumerator WaitALittleBit(int seconds) {     
        Debug.Log("WaitALittleBit start");
        timeRemaining = 0;
        flagToStopWork = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
        Debug.Log("WaitALittleBit end");
        flagToStopWork = false;        
    }

    void Update() {            
        if (timeRemaining > workLimit) {
            Debug.Log("reset all");            
            int rand = Random.Range(1, 3);
            StartCoroutine(WaitALittleBit(rand));
        }

        if (flagToStopWork)
            return;

        timeRemaining += Time.deltaTime * 5f;
        Debug.Log("do work " + (byte) timeRemaining);        
    }
}
```

Тут используются [Корутины](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/Coroutines.html), [корутины](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/570498/191482) и еще раз [корутины](https://habrahabr.ru/post/216185/).

В чем смысл кода:

Мы делаем какую-то работу (в данном случае делаем что-то пока `timeRemaining < workLimit`). Делаем мы это только в одном случае: если нам позволяет специальный флаг `flagToStopWork`. Если он `true`, то мы просто не пускаем логику выполнения дальше, то есть пишем `return`, ибо нефиг.

Также смотрим, если вдруг `timeRemaining` превысило лимит, то вот тут-то запускаем корутину, которая выполняется асинхронно и, что важно **НЕ останавливает весь главный поток!!!** 
Эта корутина как раз управляет флагом, устанавливая его значение в `true`, чтобы в методе `Update` не выполнялась работа, а после нескольких секунд (в данном случае их задает как раз-таки `Random.Range`) вновь делает флаг `false`, что запускает опять работу в методе `Update`. Также, попутно, она (корутина) сбрасывает `timeRemaining` в ноль.

Comment: Больше спасибо, ваш код даже лучше чем надо, работает идеально.

Comment: Костыльно, и тут некорректно, корутина в unity выполняется в главном потоке, а значит она может останавливать главный поток, если вычисления слишком велики( зависит от того как хорошо распределишь нагрузку между yield). Это как сделать одномерный массив, и построить над ним обертку для работы с ним как с многомерным, иллюзия асинхронности. Хоть Unity и однопоточна, потоки все же можно использовать, но избегая Unity api.

Comment: @Xumera_hZ конечно же, сделать второй таймер, который оборачивает условием `if` целый зависимый блок с логикой работы, которая может растянуться на много строк - выглядит гораздо менее костыльно, чем банальное выставление флага, ага. потом еще один таймер на какое-нибудь условие и еще один `if` . Нет, благодарю.

Comment: Все зависит от задачи, и этого решения здесь более чем достаточно, что мешает обернуть блок логики в отдельную функцию? Не стоит тратить время на "а если то/это/а вдруг", это не архитектура, а просто алгоритм.
А вот allocate от корутин, от new WaitForSeconds, overhead для одного таймера, а если этот скрипт повесить на 100 объектов. И задумаешься, что пару вложенных if, не так уж и страшно для этой задачи. Если надо сделать 10 последовательных логик с разным периодом времени, то можно подумать о корутинах ( также можно решить с 1 if для таймера и состояниями для последовательных действий)