# Как одновременно запустить два метода?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы два метода выполнялись одновременно, при попытке через thread выбивает
UnityException: get_transform can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;

public class BrickCutter : MonoBehaviour
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    private void Update()
    {
        Thread CutRL = new Thread(CutterRL);
        Thread CutFB = new Thread(CutterFB);

        CutFB.Start();
        CutRL.Start();
    }
    
    private void CutterRL()
    {
        RaycastHit _checkRayRight;
            
        if (BrickFreezer.falled)
        {
            Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(-Mathf.Abs(transform.localScale.x) / 2, 0, 0), Vector3.up, out _checkRayRight, Mathf.Infinity);
            

            if (_checkRayRight.transform != null)
            {
                Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(-Mathf.Abs(transform.localScale.x) / 2, 0, 0), Vector3.up, out hit, Mathf.Infinity);

                Spawner.lastBrickScaleX = hit.transform.localScale.x - Mathf.Abs(hit.transform.position.x - transform.position.x);       

                hit.transform.localScale = new Vector3(Spawner.lastBrickScaleX, hit.transform.localScale.y, hit.transform.localScale.z);
                hit.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - (transform.position.x - hit.transform.position.x) / 2, hit.transform.position.y, hit.transform.position.z);

                Spawner.lastXPosition = hit.transform.position.x;
                Spawner.lastZPosition = hit.transform.position.z;

                Destroy(this);
            }
            else
            {
                Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(Mathf.Abs(transform.localScale.x) / 2, 0, 0), Vector3.up, out hit, Mathf.Infinity);

                Spawner.lastBrickScaleX = hit.transform.localScale.x-Mathf.Abs(hit.transform.position.x - transform.position.x);

                hit.transform.localScale = new Vector3(Spawner.lastBrickScaleX, hit.transform.localScale.y, hit.transform.localScale.z);
                hit.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - (transform.position.x - hit.transform.position.x) / 2, hit.transform.position.y, hit.transform.position.z);

                Spawner.lastXPosition = hit.transform.position.x;
                Spawner.lastZPosition = hit.transform.position.z;

                Destroy(this);
            }


        }
    }

    private void CutterFB()
    {
        RaycastHit _checkRayFront;

        if (BrickFreezer.falled)
        {

            Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, -Mathf.Abs(transform.localScale.z) / 2), Vector3.up, out _checkRayFront, Mathf.Infinity);
            

            if (_checkRayFront.transform != null)
            {
                Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, -Mathf.Abs(transform.localScale.z) / 2), Vector3.up, out hit, Mathf.Infinity);

                Spawner.lastBrickScaleZ = hit.transform.localScale.z - Mathf.Abs(hit.transform.position.z - transform.position.z);

                hit.transform.localScale = new Vector3(hit.transform.localScale.x, hit.transform.localScale.y, Spawner.lastBrickScaleZ);
                hit.transform.position = new Vector3(hit.transform.position.x, hit.transform.position.y, transform.position.z - (transform.position.z - hit.transform.position.z) / 2);

                Spawner.lastXPosition = hit.transform.position.x;
                Spawner.lastZPosition = hit.transform.position.z;

                Destroy(this);
            }
            else
            {
                Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Abs(transform.localScale.z) / 2), Vector3.up, out hit, Mathf.Infinity);

                Spawner.lastBrickScaleZ = hit.transform.localScale.z - Mathf.Abs(hit.transform.position.z - transform.position.z);

                hit.transform.localScale = new Vector3(hit.transform.localScale.x, hit.transform.localScale.y, Spawner.lastBrickScaleZ);
                hit.transform.position = new Vector3(hit.transform.position.x, hit.transform.position.y, transform.position.z - (transform.position.z - hit.transform.position.z) / 2);

                Spawner.lastXPosition = hit.transform.position.x;
                Spawner.lastZPosition = hit.transform.position.z;

                Destroy(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Зачем в Unity корутины?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570498/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-unity-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать потоки через Thread далеко не лучшая идея (особенно в Unity). Существуют более удобные инструменты как для асинхронных, так и для параллельных вычислений.

Для асинхронности в Unity можно использовать корутины. Однако их я также не рекомендую использовать, так как корутины могут снизить читаемость кода, и работать с ними не так удобно, как с другими вариантами.
Взамен, начиная с Unity 2021 (возможно и с более старшей версии) можно использовать System.Threading.Tasks.Task () или, еще лучше, подключить библиотеку [UniTask](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask).

Для параллельных вычислений можно использовать [Jobs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystem.html). Для рейкастов есть даже отдельный класс [RaycastCommand](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastCommand.html).